# Error in http-proxy module : Must provide a proper URL as target

Tags: node.js, http, proxy

I'm new in `Node.JS` and deployed the first application on VPS. 
After running on port `8000`, i decided create a `http-proxy` for forward each domain to its specific port . 
I worte a little application like here :

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var option = {
    router : {
        'domain.com' : 'http://88.198.86.100:8000'
    }
};

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(option);
proxyServer.listen(80);
```

`88.198.86.100 is my server ip`.

So, my problem here is shown , when i typed `88.198.86.100` in my browser PC (Google Chrome), my proxy application in server was carshed and gave this error :

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Nodejs\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:119
throw err;
^

Error: Must provide a proper URL as target
at ProxyServer.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Nodejs\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:68:35)
at Server.closure (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Nodejs\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:125:43)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

I want to someone enter IP server into the each browser, my application will not crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //below code works for me

 var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
 var proxy = httpProxy.createProxy();

 var options = {
     'foo.com': 'http://foo.com:8001',
     'bar.com': 'http://bar.com:8002'
    }
    require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
          target: options[req.headers.host]
          });
    }).listen(80);
```